# Override AgGrid row checkbox with custom SVG React

Tags: css, svg, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have the follow styles to override the AGgrid Checkbox, but I need it override icon with an SVG. How does it work, I am trying something like this. Applying it on div theme suggested here https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-styling/

```
      '& .ag-checkbox-input-wrapper:after': {
        content: `url("data:image/svg+xml; utf8, ` + logo + `") !important`,
        top: '1px !important',
        right: '1px !important',
        bottom: '1px !important',
        left: '1px !important',
        opacity: 1,
        borderRadius: '50%',
        background: 'white !important',
        color: 'blue !important'
      },
```